# Do spawned threads automatically run as the identity of the user?

Tags: c#, security, multithreading, windows-security

ie

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var thread = new Thread(WhoAmI);
    thread.Start();
}

static void WhoAmI()
{ 
    //can i access network resources as the user who ran Main?
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they do.

```
// So yes, you can.
```

Comment: you were 1st so giving you the points, + nice // comment humour

Answer (score 3):

Threads don't have identity, processes do.  So yes.

Edit: As Michael points out, it is possible for a thread's execution context to impersonate a user other than the one that owns the current process.    But this will not happen unless you do it explicitly.

Comment: Threads can have a separate identity if they're impersonating.

Comment: Michael is right.  Thread.ExecutionContext can flow this identity onto other threads.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. In fact, it would take some effort to make the Thread able to access resources as a different user.